# Scan components of different maven modules/JARs in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two Maven modules. 
The first one, called "application", contains the `spring boot` Application class that just contains these lines:

```
package org.example.application;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"org.example.model", "org.example"})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

In the same Maven module and package, `org.example.application`, I have a `RestController` that uses a `Component` that in turn uses the components of the other Maven module described below.

The other Maven module, called "model", contains the `spring boot` components (crud-repositories, entities etc). All those classes are under the same package structure as the first Maven module (`org.example`) but in subpackages of that, like `org.example.model.entities`, `org.example.model.repositories` etc.

So, the flow is like this:

Maven module `application` in package *org.example*:
`SpringBootApplication -> RestController -> MyComponent`

And the components that should be autowired in `MyComponent` are the ones in the `model` Maven module under the package `org.example.model`.

But when I start the application I just get the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field myRepository in org.example.MyComponent required a bean of type 'org.example.model.repositories.MyRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.example.model.repositories.MyRepository' in your configuration.
```

`org.example.model.repositories.MyRepository` does exist in Maven module "model" but cannot be found by the SpringBootApplication class!

As you can see, I have tried to explicitly define the scan components to:
`@ComponentScan({"org.example.model", "org.example"})` but that does not seem to help.

So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The first thing that you should wonder is :  why do you declare `@ComponentScan` while one of the goal of `@SpringBootApplication` is (among other things) to enable the component scan ?
From [Spring Boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html) :

> The `@SpringBootApplication` annotation is equivalent to using
>   `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan` with their
>   default attributes

Note that when on the class of your Spring Boot Application, you declare `@ComponentScan` to specify a value as `basePackages`, it  overrides the `basePackages` used by default by `@SpringBootApplication` that is the current package where the class resides.  So to have as base package both the package of the Spring Boot Application class and the additional packages that were missing, you have to explicitly set them.

Besides `basePackages` is recursive. So to enable the scan both for classes locating in the `"org.example"` and `"org.example.model"` packages, specifying `"org.example"` is enough as `"org.example.model"` is a sub-package of it.

Try that :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"org.example"})
```

Or alternatively :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("org.example")
```

---

### When specify @EnableJpaRepositories/@ComponentScan/scanBasePackages in a Spring Boot Application ?

As you design your Spring Boot application layout, your have two cases :

**1) case (to favor) where you use a package layout that provides the auto configuration of Spring Boot with zero configuration.**

To summarize : if your classes annotated with Spring Bean stereotypes : `@Component`, `@Repositories`, `@Repositories`,... are located in the same package or a sub-package of the Spring Boot Application class, declaring only
`@SpringBootApplication` is all you need.

**2) case (to avoid) where you don't use a package layout that provides the auto configuration of Spring Boot with zero configuration.**

It generally  means that you have candidate classes to scan that are not in the package (or sub-package) of your class annotated  with `@SpringBootApplication`.
In this case, you add the `scanBasePackages` attribute or add `@ComponentScan` to specify packages to scan.
But additionally, if your repositories are not located in a package or sub-package of your class annotated  with `@SpringBootApplication`, something else has to be declared such as : `@EnableJpaRepositories(="packageWhereMyRepoAreLocated")`

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-use-spring-data-repositories) about this part (emphasis is mine) :

> **80.3 Use Spring Data Repositories**
>
> Spring Data can create implementations of @Repository interfaces of
>   various flavors. **Spring Boot handles all of that for you, as long as
>   those @Repositories are included in the same package (or a
>   sub-package) of your @EnableAutoConfiguration class.**
>
> For many applications, all you need is to put the right Spring Data
>   dependencies on your classpath (there is a
>   spring-boot-starter-data-jpa for JPA and a
>   spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb for Mongodb) and create some
>   repository interfaces to handle your @Entity objects. Examples are in
>   the JPA sample and the Mongodb sample.
>
> **Spring Boot tries to guess the location of your @Repository
>   definitions, based on the @EnableAutoConfiguration it finds. To get
>   more control, use the @EnableJpaRepositories annotation (from Spring
>   Data JPA).**

---

### Examples

**1) case (to favor) where you use a package layout that provides the auto configuration of Spring Boot with zero configuration.**

With a Spring Boot application declared in the `org.example` package, and all bean classes (Repositories included)  declared in the same package or a sub-package of `org.example`, the following declaration is enough for the Spring Boot application :

```
package org.example;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The repositories could be located in the `org.example.repository` package such as :

```
package org.example.repository;

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends  JpaRepository<Foo, Long>,  { }
```

and

```
package org.example.repository;

@Repository
public interface BarRepository extends  JpaRepository<Bar, Long>,  { }
```

The controllers could be located in the `org.example.controller` package :

```
package org.example.controller;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/foos")
public class FooController  {...}
```

and so for...

**2) case (to avoid) where you don't use a package layout that provides the auto configuration of Spring Boot with zero configuration.**

With a Spring Boot application declared in the `org.example.application` package, and not all bean classes (Repositories included)  declared in the same package or a sub-package of `org.example.application`, the following declaration will be required for the Spring Boot application :

```
package org.example.application;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= {
                      "org.example", 
                      "org.thirdparty.repository"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("org.thirdparty.repository")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the bean classes could be as below.

The repositories that may come from an external a JAR could be located in the `org.thirdparty.repository` package such as :

```
package org.thirdparty.repository;

@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends  JpaRepository<Foo, Long>,  { }
```

and

```
package org.thirdparty.repository;

@Repository
public interface BarRepository extends  JpaRepository<Bar, Long>,  { }
```

The controllers could be located in the `org.example.controller` package :

```
package org.example.controller

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/foos")
public class FooController  {...}
```

and so for...

**Conclusion** : defining the Spring Boot application in the base package of your namespace is really encouraged to make the Spring Boot configuration as simple as possible.

Comment: I have tried that too but I get the same error. So I then supposed the component scan was made in the same package *and* in the same JAR/Maven module. I would like to get the SpringBootApplication to scan for components in the same package *but of another* JAR/maven module.

Comment: The component scan is performed at runtime. Whereever the class resides, if it is in the classpath it should work. Can you post the pom.xml of the projects ?

Comment: Ah, I now found a solution. In my post above, I have obfuscated the code a bit, and the `SpringBootApplication` class  actually resides in the `org.example.application` package. If I move the `SpringBootApplication` to the package `org.example` then it works. But I still don´t understand why it cannot be under `org.example.application` when I explicit make the component scan to scan everything under `org.example`, like `@ComponentScan({"org.example.model", "org.example"})`.

Comment: Great :) Is it not related to `@SpringBootApplication` that causes the default scan package to the current package `org.example.application` as you don't specify `scanBasePackages` attribute?  Can you try again with `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"org.example"})` as indicated in my answer?  And remove `@ComponentScan` that is redundant. It should work.

Comment: If you add @ComponentScan, then the packages specified in there will only apply for the component scan of Spring beans, not Spring Data repositories. If you would want to specify the packages for that, you would either have to add the appropriate `@Enable*Repositories` with the package, or just add the scanBasePackages attribute to SpringBootApplication, which applies to component scan, Spring Data repository, entity scanning etc.

Comment: I had the same problem and setting scanBasePackages on SpringBootApplication didn't work for me. Adding @EnableJpaRepositories with proper base package as dunni said did the trick.

Comment: @NimaAJ  Thanks for this remark. I think that it is due to mismatch between the package of the Spring Boot application and which one of your repositories. I updated.

Comment: EnableJpaRepositories solve my problems. I am wondering why add scancomponent or change SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"org.example"}) doesn't work in my case.

Comment: @Ben Spring Boot handles all of that for you, as long as those `@Repositories` are included in the same package (or a sub-package) of your `@EnableAutoConfiguration` class. If you repository classes are not located in the package or subpackage of your spring boot app class, this behavior is expected.