# Spring Boot can't scan anotation with mutiple module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I using spring boot and design by mutiple modules. Below my project structure :

Module shop core :
Package name : **com.baotrung.core.business**
I design some sub package : model, repositores, services

**Maven :**

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>shop-core</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- shop-core-model !-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baotrung</groupId>
            <artifactId>shop-core-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

**CategoryService**

```
 public interface CategoryService {

    List<Object> countProductsByCategories(MerchantStore store, List<Long> categoryIds);

    List<Category> listByStoreAndParent(MerchantStore store, Category category);

    PersistableCategory saveCategories(MerchantStore store, PersistableCategory persistableCategory);

    Category findById(Long id);

    List<ReadableCategory> findCategories(MerchantStore store, int dept, Language language,List<String> filters);
```

}

**Categories Service Impl**

```
@Service
public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

    @Autowired
    private CategoriesRepository categoryRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Mapper<Category,ReadableCategory> categoryReadableCategoryMapper;

    //some method
```

**@Repository**

```
public interface CategoriesRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long>, CategoryRepositoryCustom {

 }

public interface CategoryRepositoryCustom {

    List<Object> countProductsByCategories(MerchantStore store, List<Long> categoryIds);

    List<Category> listByStoreAndParent(MerchantStore store, Category category);


    }

@Repository
public class CategoryRepositoryCustomImpl implements CategoryRepositoryCustom {

// some method impl
}
```

I also create module **shopping-ap**p and used **shop-code** dependency into it. Look like :

Maven:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>spring-shopping-project</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.baotrung</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>shopping-app</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baotrung</groupId>
            <artifactId>shop-core-model</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baotrung</groupId>
            <artifactId>shop-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

and in module **shopping-app** , i create package **com.baotrung.web** and create some sub package : **repository**,**services**,**model**... and create application with name **Application.class** look like :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.baotrung.core.business","com.baotrung.*"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }
}
```

But when i boot **Application.class** it throw me exception

```
Field categoryRepository in com.baotrung.core.business.services.CategoryServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.baotrung.core.business.repositories.CategoriesRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.baotrung.core.business.repositories.CategoriesRepository' in your configuration.
```

I can't understand why, because i has add anotation in **CategoriesRepository** with @**Repository** as above in module **com.baotrung.core.business.repositories.CategoriesRepository**. Why spring can't find me bean from **com.baotrung.core.business.repositories** because it a really define. Please help me?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41430051/scan-components-of-different-maven-modules-jars-in-a-spring-boot-application as the question seems similar?

Comment: let me check it. Thank so much

Comment: remove CategoryRepositoryCustom  from public interface CategoriesRepository extends CrudRepository<Category, Long>, CategoryRepositoryCustom and check if it's going to be okay

Comment: no it not help me. Problem still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to this by add `@EnableJpaRepositories` and `@EntityScan` :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.baotrung.*"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.baotrung.*"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class,args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. When i add : 
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.baotrung.*")
in Application.class it throw me exception : 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.baotrung.core.model.catalog.category.Category

Then i add @EntityScan("com.baotrung.*") it work . Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to cleanup/restructure your package hierarchy to make it work. 
It should work without any additional annotations, check my github where I created a test for your given example: https://github.com/fabapp/stackoverflow58672323

If you place your Application class in the root package of your application, e.g. `com.baotrung.shop`, the component scan will start from this package downward. All other components should reside in this or in sub packages and things will be easier and you'll need less boilerplate code.
Putting the Application class in a parallel package (and below) to your other components (as you did) will force you to set the path for the component scan to find these (and future) components which didn't work as expected.